My new headphones don't work
I bought a a pair of Hi-X15 headphones and they don't work when I plug them in. They have a two lines TRS jack. My old and cheap headphones seem to work alright. They have a three line TRRS jack. I have a msi tomahawk x670e motherboard and I looked up the documentation where I should plug in the headphones. I mention that my old headphones work when I plug them in.
The output of aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [PG42UQ]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALCS1200A Analog [ALCS1200A Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALCS1200A Digital [ALCS1200A Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

When I plug my old headphones it changes like so (I've put only the difference)
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALCS1200A Analog [ALCS1200A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

But when I plug in the new headphones it is like this
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALCS1200A Analog [ALCS1200A Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Does the Subdivices: 0/1 mean they aren't detected? The headphones don't have any visible damage. Neither the box in which they were packaged. Are they broken or can I do something?
